# Fail to log in after installing from windows 8

Tags: login

installed Ubuntu 14.0.4 by erasing all previous data.
Previous OS was windows 8.
Now it will not let me log in.
After inserting my password it makes the drum sound and just goes back to the log in screen.
Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 0):

The probability is big that you have a typo in your password during installation. Solution: re-installation! ;)
Make sure you type the right keys depending on the localization of your keyboard (German keyboard, English keyboard, Russian keyboard...)